# Set JAVA_HOME ubuntu: path not found

Tags: java

I am trying to set `JAVA_HOME`  in my ubuntu machine ,for that i've added the following path in `/etc/environment`

`"JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin"`

and reloaded the `source /etc/environment`.

but i got the following error

> bash: JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin: No such
>   file or directory

But the path is exists

**Note**

The same error occures while i am trying to install hyperledger sawtooth 
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html.

hyperledger sawtooth ububtu installation requires the java

Ubuntu version

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Also i've adde the following in `.bashrc` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: Use [alternatives](https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2011/10/13/configuring-different-jdks-with-alternatives/). And I don't really think you're Batman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/environment` is as well a bash script, so change the line with

```
"JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin"
```

which is not bash variable syntax to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Also note the above uses the base directory not the `bin` directory for the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: JAVA_HOME should only point up to the base path of JDK dir. Here, it should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: probably, but that's another issue, OP only complains about syntax error.